# equivalent definitions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\pi :C^{'} \rightarrow C$ is a double unramified cover of a complex Riemann surface named $C$, we can define the involution sheet exchange $\tau: C^{'} \rightarrow C$.
We say that a meromorphic function $f$ on $C^{'}$ is anti-invariant respect to $\tau$ if the following relation hold: $$f=-f\circ \tau .$$
Is there an equivalent definition of anti-invariant function that involves the double unramified cover $\pi$?.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there exists *Norm map*, see [E. Arbarello et al.: "Geometry of algebraic curves", Volume I, App. B.1]. Then you need write
$$
Nm(f)=0.
$$